# Cant debug software with ida

Tags: ida, anti-debugging

I have software that run on windows well.

I tried to debug it with IDA (local win32 debug) but when I start it I see that exeption throw and I cant debug it.

I dont use breakpoints

Is that anti debug mechanism?

What can I do to fix it and debug?

Comment: You've to provide that error as your question doesn't make sense without that information ;) possible cause: file is an installer. Obfuscated .net etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes application throws exceptions and its ok. You may try to pass it back to the application and continue the execution, IDA actually suggests you this when exception happens. If you keep coming back to the same exception again and again - this could be an antidebugging trick.